# Google PageSpeed is requesting that I enable compression for files that are hosted by Google

Tags: google-maps, compression, gzip, pagespeed

When running the Page Speed test on pages with a Google map embedded I get this:

> Should Fix:
>   Enable compression
>   Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can reduce the number of bytes sent over the network.
>   Enable compression for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 136.4KiB (67% reduction).
>   Compressing https://maps.google.com/…95,0.006295&z=10&output=embed&iwloc=near could save 135.3KiB (67% reduction).
>   Compressing https://maps.google.com/…=kEXbUrP4JNGygQSk7ICgAw&hl=en&country=us could save 1.1KiB (71% reduction).

---

The page gets 99/100 for both mobile and desktop when the map is taken out, but drops down to 85/100 and 87/100 with it included. It would be very odd if Google did not follow it's own recommendations for resource compression. From my understanding of the matter -- which is limited -- , the only way to enable this is via .htaccess on the server that the files are being hosted on. Anyone have any advice or suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can't do anything to external resource, your side is already optimized

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure. Thanks for the quick response